# Angular 6 and AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken

I have searched a lot but i don't find how to implement the AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken.
I'm creating an Angular 6 spa with TypeScript, connecting to an endpoint .NET Core 2.1
In ConfigureServices added

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
```

before AddMvc()
added in Configure

```
app.Use(next => context =>
{
    string path = context.Request.Path.Value;
    if (string.Equals(path, "/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || string.Equals(path, "/index.html", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // We can send the request token as a JavaScript-readable cookie,
        // and Angular will use it by default.
        var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
        context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
    }
    return next(context);
});
```

The Angular documentation is not clear, if i understood well i should read a cookie named X-XSRF-TOKEN and transmit back in the http call as header: but i try to read this cookie in angular (using ngx-cookie-service, with a code as this.cookieSvc.get("X-XSRF-TOKEN")) this cookie is empty.
If someone could help, thanks.

Comment: You are *setting* a cookie named `XSRF-TOKEN` but attempting to *read* a cookied named `X-XSRF-TOKEN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, check points below to understand your issue better.

1. For [CookieXSRFStrategy](https://angular.io/api/http/CookieXSRFStrategy), it configure `XSRF-TOKEN` as `cookie name` and `X-XSRF-TOKEN` as `header Name` for `XSRF`.
2. To correspond to `Angular`, `Asp.Net Core` work with this convention just like you done.

   - Configure your app to provide a token in a cookie called XSRF-TOKEN
   - Configure the antiforgery service to look for a header named X-XSRF-TOKEN.

So, if you want to get `AntiforgeryToken` from Angular site, try query cookies by `XSRF-TOKEN`.