# How to handle AutoValidateAntiForgeryToken through ajax callsl in .Net Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am working with `.Net Core 2.2`, I am using `AutoValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute for every action in controller.
It is working fine for submit calls(through begin form submit), where as for ajax calls the controller action is not hitting- I don't know how to handle `AutoValidateAntiForgeryToken`  for ajax calls.

Kindly help me.

Thanks!!!

Comment: have a look at [Angular 6 and AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52416837/2417602) it might help in understanding the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In .Net Core 2.2 , for ajax calls we need to set `_RequestVerificationToken` in headers .
To access that header we need to add it to the services like

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "__RequestVerificationToken");
```

Here is my javascript code.

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
    },
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data: request,
    success: function (response) {

        $("#ImageTable").html(response);
        callback(response);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //console.log('Error calling rules engine. Error thrown: ' + JSON.stringify(errorThrown) + '. Request: ' + JSON.stringify(request));
    }
});
```

Here is my controller action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Confirm(string tabId)
    {
      //some code
    }
```